# How to get MobileFirst 6.3 server for free for the purpose of learning

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have been given an assignment to take up training on IBM MobileFirst 6.3 Server Administration. I want to show the students how to install MobileFirst server and configure it. But after going through the documentation, i realized , the server component is not part of MobileFirst Foundation developer edition, which is free (Correct me if i am wrong).

How do i show the server installation and configuration without buying the license ? Is there an alternative here ?

Thanks..

Comment: Although Idan's statement is correct, if you are teaching an IBM-sponsored course, you should consider talking to your local IBM representative to see if a complementary copy can be made available for the course, or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

As you mentioned, the server component is not free and you must purchase it from IBM.
This is really not a question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as an IBM partner ? (https://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/mem/ContentHandler/partnerworld-member)